# Yank visual selection with modifications in a terminal-buffer

Tags: cut-copy-paste, terminal-buffer

Upon writing a code, sometimes I open a terminal split with `:term` to test it by issuing some commands and checking some output. As an example, this is a fragment of what I have executed in a split terminal:

```
...
I$[12:38]~/Stack>cat file
time;area;temperature;pumpmotor;diameter
1;2;3;4;5
6;7;8;9;10
I$[12:38]~/Stack>awk -f measurements.awk file
I$[12:38]~/Stack>cat *.csv
time,area,diameter
1,2,5
6,7,10
...
```

Now, I wish to copy that that snippet and paste it on my browser (for an answer in Stack :)), so what I usually do is

1. `C-W N` Put the terminal in "text-mode";
2. Position the cursor in the last line I want to copy, in this case `6,7,10`;
3. `V` Start visual mode and go up to the first line I want to copy, `I$[12:38]~/Stack>cat file`;
4. `"+y` Yank the selection to clipboard.

That does the job as expected, but the prompt is distracting and useless, thus I want to reduce it to `I$`  (ideally it would shrink to `$` , but that would add still more complexity to the task and I prefer to drop it). But since that is a terminal, I cannot modify it with `:'<,'>s/\[.*>/ /` between steps 3 and 4 to get rid of the prompt before yanking.

**Is there some easy intermediate step to sanitize the prompt without resorting to copy the terminal contents to an additional ordinary buffer?** In case I were not clear, the clipboard should contain:

```
I$ cat file
time;area;temperature;pumpmotor;diameter
1;2;3;4;5
6;7;8;9;10
I$ awk -f measurements.awk file
I$ cat *.csv
time,area,diameter
1,2,5
6,7,10
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @filbranden Thank you for your courtesy :)

Comment: I noticed your contributions on Vim questions on the other stacks, so I'm really glad to see you finally made your way here :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`substitute()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29) on the contents of the register to make a replacement, and use a `:let` command to assign it back to the clipboard register.

For example, start by copying it to the default register in step 4, with `y` (instead of `"+y`.)

And then use the `:let` command to apply a `substitute()` on the contents of the default register and assign that to the clipboard register:

```
:let @+ = substitute(@", '\[[^\n]*>', ' ', 'g')
```

Note that you need to use a non-greedy version of the regular expression (`[^\n]*` instead of `.*`) since `substitute()` will apply it to the text as a whole and not line by line, so the `.` will match newlines.

You could of course further automate this by creating a mapping, say `<Leader>y` from visual mode, that would yank the contents into the default register, perform any necessary modifications and finally store that into the clipboard register.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections @Quasímodo!

Comment: You are welcome! I only noticed it when a line with `[` showed up. Also, thanks for the thorough explanation, it would have been much more difficult to grasp what was happening without it.